# "Jump to definition" in Firefox DevTools' console jumps to minified JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

I want debug JavaScript in prettify mode using the Firefox Developer Tools, but after clicking on the *jump to definition* icon, it switches to the default version of the JavaScript and not the prettyfied version.

See this video:
http://bayanbox.ir/view/1345913938885179254/prettify.webm

Is this a bug?

Comment: Is this *jump to definition* icon a standard feature of the Firefox DevTools? I don't see that using Nightly 60.0a1 (2018-01-28).

Comment: @SebastianZartner , yes , i dont install any add-on, i only download `firefox dev` deb package for my kali, and install it, see this image : http://bayanbox.ir/view/1983429465436891872/Screenshot-from-2018-01-29-17-22-50.png

Comment: @SebastianZartner and see this http://bayanbox.ir/view/178723062349462853/Screenshot-from-2018-01-29-17-23-18.png

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this is a bug in the DevTools, which should be fixed together with [bug 1433373](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1433373).